# Error in trying to open dialog box from a widget button in python

Tags: python, popup, widget, tkinter, dialog

I'm new to python. I'm trying to open a dialog box to get a value from within a widget that does a list of other staff allready.

But getting errors and can't figure out what to do.

Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter,Tkconstants,tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *
import csv
import numpy
import math
import numpy.random as nrnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shutil
import tkMessageBox
global filesavepath
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.mymaster=master
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.importbutton=Button(frame,text='Import Data',command=self.importdata)
        self.importbutton.pack()
        self.executebutton=Button(frame,text='Execute',command=self.popup)
        self.executebutton.pack()
        self.distribution_rep=Button(frame,text='Repeat Purchase Score Distribution',command=self.distrepbutton)
        self.distribution_rep.pack()
        self.distribution_churn=Button(frame,text='Churn Probability Distribution',command=self.distchurnbutton)
       self.distribution_churn.pack()
       self.exitbutton=Button(frame,text='Exit',command=self.exitapp)
       self.exitbutton.pack()
       self.file_opt=options={}
       options['defaultextension']=''
       options['filetypes']=[('allfiles','.*'),('textfiles','.txt')]
       options['initialdir']='C:\\'
       options['initialfile']='myfile.txt'
       options['parent']=root
       options['title']='Thisisatitle'
    def importdata(self):
        filename=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        filesavepath="C:/input_full.csv"
        shutil.copy2(filename,filesavepath)
        if filename:
            return open(filename,'r')

    def popup(self):
        top = self.top = Tkinter.Toplevel(self)
        myLabel = Tkinter.Label(top, text='Enter your username below')
        myLabel.pack()

        self.myEntryBox = Tkinter.Entry(top)
        self.myEntryBox.pack()

        mySubmitButton = Tkinter.Button(top, text='Done', command=self.execbutton)
        mySubmitButton.pack()
    def execbutton(self):
        if self.myEntryBox.get() != "":
            self.timevalue = self.myEntryBox.get()
            self.top.destroy()
        execfile("Repeat Purchase Algo in python v6")
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Job Done", "Probability Computation completed")       
    def send(self):
        global timevalue
        timevalue=self.myEntryBox.get()
        self.top.destroy()
    def distrepbutton(self):
        plt.hist(prob,bins=10,normed=TRUE)
        plt.xlabel('Probability')
        plt.title('Histogram of Repeat Purchase Probability')
        plt.show()
    def distchurnbutton(self):
        plt.hist(churn_prob,bins=10,normed=TRUE)
        plt.ylabel('Probability')
        plt.title('Histogram of Churn Probability')
        plt.show()
    def exitapp(self):
        self.mymaster.destroy()

root=Tk()
root.title('Repeat Puchase Widget')
app=App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So as may be apparent to you, I'm importing  dataset with an Import button, executing some analysis in another code through a button called Execute, and then showing some graphs.

What I wanted was to open a pop up kind of window on click of "Execute" button that will input a value. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/widget_repeat_purchase_v4", line 42, in popup
    top = self.top = Tkinter.Toplevel(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2017, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1965, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1943, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'tk'
```

I've no idea what to do. Please help.

Comment: If you wander why there are som many imports, please note they are for the second python script I'm running through here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the toplevel widget, you are passing `self` as the first argument. Tkinter requires that this be a parent widget. However, in your code `self` does not represent a widget.

In your specific case you want to pass in `self.mymaster` rather than `self`:

```
top = self.top = Tkinter.Toplevel(self.mymaster)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, it worked...I didn't realize the mistake...really thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Tkinter.Toplevel()` instead of `Tkinter.Toplevel(self)`